# Create IBW Disk for Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-pe, answer-file, wadk

I am currently changing our OS from Windows 7 Embedded to Windows 10 IoT LTSB Enterprise 1607.

In Windows 7 Embedded we created a IBW disk using Windows Embedded Standard 7 Image configuration editor by "Create IBW Image with full Distribution Share.." option. This disk gave us the option to boot from a disk and use a WinPE GUI in order to "deploy an answer file or WIM".

I want to create an IBW disk like that for Windows 10.
I tried to find a way to do it using Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (Windows ADK), but didn't find it there.

How can I create such a disk ?